# How to join three tables in linq with child table sum

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have three tables, quarter, month and Items

**QuarterTable**

```
  QuarterId    Status    Amount
```

**MonthTable**

```
  MonthId  QuarterId  Amount
```

**Items**

```
  ItemId  MonthId  ProductId  Amount   DateTime
```

---

Product items amount should be sum by month.
And I want to query in linq to result like under:

```
Quarter1 => { Month1 => { items from month1 }, 
              Month2 => { items from month2 }, 
              Month3=> { items from month3 }
            }

Quarter2 => { Month4 => { items from month4 },
              Month5 => { items from month5 }, 
              Month6 => { items from month6 }
            }

Quarter3 => { Month7 => { items from month7 },
              Month8 { items from month8 }, 
              Month9 { items from month9 }
            }
```

This is LINQ I have tried :

```
from MonthTable in MonthTable 
select new
       { 
         a = MonthTable, 
         b = (from Items in Items 
              group Items by new { Items.MonthId, Items.ProductId, Items.DateTime.Month, Items.Amount } 
              into newGroup 
              where newGroup.Key.MonthId == MonthTable.MonthId 
              select new { b = newGroup.Sum(x => x.Amount), ProductId = newGroup.ProductId })
       }
```

I am new to linq can anyone please help me how to do it

Comment: @Orlando, sorry but people in here will not write code for you, but will help you with your specific problem. So I would suggest you to try it yourself later show what you have tried and we can help.

Comment: from MonthTable in MonthTable
select new { a = MonthTable, b = (from Items in Items
group Items by new { Items.MonthId, Items.ProductId, Items.DateTime.Month, Items.Amount  } into newGroup
where newGroup.Key.MonthId == MonthTable.MonthId
select new {  b = newGroup.Sum(x => x.Amount), ProductId = newGroup.ProductId })}

Comment: I am not sure if the sub query will reduce my performance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could see some DB Schema design issues with your Table designs. Nevertheless the following would help you. I haven't tested it. But should work fine.

```
var JoinedCollection = from qt in QuarterTables
                       join mt in MonthTables on qt.QuarterId equals mt.QuarterId
                       join it in Items on mt.MonthId equals it.MonthId
                       select new
                       {
                           Quarter = qt.QuarterId,
                           Month = mt.MonthId,
                           Item = it.ItemId,
                           Amount = it.Amount
                       };

var GroupedCollection = JoinedCollection.GroupBy(jc => new
{
    jc.Quarter,
    jc.Month
});

var SummedCollection = GroupedCollection.Select(gc => new
{
    Quarter = gc.Key.Quarter,
    Month = gc.Key.Month,
    Total = gc.ToList().Sum(a => a.Amount)
});
```

OR Combined as

```
var SummedCollection = from qt in QuarterTables
                       join mt in MonthTables on qt.QuarterId equals mt.QuarterId
                       join it in Items on mt.MonthId equals it.MonthId
                       group new
                       {
                           Quarter = qt.QuarterId,
                           Month = mt.MonthId,
                           Item = it.ItemId,
                           Amount = it.Amount
                       }
                       by new
                       {
                           qt.QuarterId,
                           mt.MonthId
                       } into gc
                       select new
                       {
                           Quarter = gc.Key.QuarterId,
                           Month = gc.Key.MonthId,
                           Total = gc.ToList().Sum(a => a.Amount)
                       };
```

Comment: Do you also want to group by `Item`. If so, is it based on `ItemId` or `ProductId`?